# Change ttk.Treeview indicator image in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to change the indicator (Expand/Collapse) image for a Tkinter (Python) Treeview. However I can't find anything in the documentation that could point me towards this or if it is even possible. Does anybody have any experience doing this? (The arrows in the image below are the indicators) [image: Treeview Indicator]

Comment: Well for me arrows are actually +'s in squares which is indicative of native GUI usage. I also remember it being drawn dynamically on Windows, as in if I shrink it enough I get a sole + as the edges of the square collapses over the +.

Comment: If its native it may be harder to replace that 'image' if at all possible.

Comment: @Nae I'm using a different Tkinter theme but I'm on Windows too

Comment: I see. Well are you able to provide [mcve] nonetheless, it's not exactly required in this question I think but it would still help producing the treeview.

Answer (score -1):

If do you mean of changing Expand/Collapse view in `treeview`, you have to use:

```
treeview.item('item2', open = False)
```

The `open` parameter will change expand or collapse state.